# What's the title of the soundtrack in Ranma 1/2 Episode 20?

Tags: music, ranma

What's the title of the soundtrack played in the scene where Azusa is talking to her toys in Ranma 1/2 Episode 20? It kinda sounds like Tchaikovsky.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the name of the soundtrack from the anime, but it sounds very much like Tchaikovsky's Allegro non troppo from Piano Concerto No. 1.